# If we are not given in marriage as spirits, how does the Bride of Christ imagery work?

Tags: matthew, marriage, bride

Matthew 22:30

> For in the resurrection they neither marry, nor are given in marriage,
> but are as the angels of God in heaven.

If this is true, how can the church collective be the Bride of Christ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metaphor of the church (collectively) as a woman and bride of God or Jesus as husband appears regularly in both the OT and NT.  It should be remembered that it is only a metaphor!  Here is a sample:

- Matt 9:15 (See also Mark 2:19, Luke 5:35) - Jesus replied, “How can the guests of the bridegroom mourn while He is with them? But the time will come when the bridegroom will be taken from them; then they will fast.
- Matt 22:1-14, Luke 14:15-24 - Jesus tells the parable of the wedding banquet.
- Matt 25:1-13 - Jesus tells the parable of the 10 virgins at the great wedding
- John 3:29 - The bride belongs to the bridegroom. The friend of the bridegroom stands and listens for him, and is overjoyed to hear the bridegroom’s voice. That joy is mine, and it is now complete.
- 2 Cor 11:2 - I am jealous for you with a godly jealousy. For I promised you to one husband, to present you as a pure virgin to Christ.
- Eph 5:25-27 - Husbands, love your wives, just as Christ loved the church and gave Himself up for her to sanctify her, cleansing her by the washing with water through the word, and to present her to Himself as a glorious church, without stain or wrinkle or any such blemish, but holy and blameless.
- In the book of Revelation, we have two women: Jezebel or the harlot as a symbol of Babylon (Rev 2:20, 17:1-18:24), vs, the pure woman as a symbol of God’s faithful people the bride of the Lamb (Rev 12:1-17, 19:7, 21:9).

John 14:1-3 - this passage is based on a metaphor of marriage which assumes the following sequence of events:

1. A man decides to marry a young woman
2. He promises to marry her, and provide for her, and many other benefits
3. He then goes away to build her a house for their marriage and expected family - most often an extension of his father's house
4. During this "waiting time" the engaged woman is expected to make herself ready, remain faithful to her husband and wait for his return
5. The husband is also expected to arrange a marriage feast and ceremony, complete with invited guests
6. The husband returns at an unexpected time to claim his bride and enjoy the wedding feast
7. After the wedding, the husband takes the new bride to the home he has just completed to live with him

Again, this a very common metaphorical theme in Scripture and thus is not intended to be understood literally.  [Men could not be literally married to Jesus!]

**APPENDIX - Marriage Metaphor in the OT**

The metaphor of marriage was not new to the NT but is taken from the OT.

- The parable of the two adulterous sisters and their children (Eze 23)
- The daughter of Babylon vs the daughter of Zion (Zech 2:7, 10).
- More generally, the Old Testament uses this image of a woman to represent either faithful (Isa 62:5, Jer 2:1, 2) or unfaithful (Isa 47:1-3, Jer 2:32, Eze 16, Nah 3:4, 5) groups of people.  [See also Gal 4:21-31 which used Sarah and Hagar as metaphors.]

Comment: @Kapandaria - many thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that no text of scripture mentions "Christ" and "bride" in the same verse.

While many speak of the church as being Christ's bride, the interesting thing is that the imagery of Revelation depicts, not the church as Christ's bride, but the city of Zion--the New Jerusalem.

> And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God out
> of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. (Revelation
> 21:2, KJV)

And God is jealous for His bride.

> Thus saith the LORD of hosts; I was jealous for Zion with great
> jealousy, and I was jealous for her with great fury. (Zechariah 8:2,
> KJV)

In Jesus' parable of the wedding (see Matthew 22:2-14), we are represented as the wedding *guests*, and not as the bride.  Even in the parable of the Ten Virgins (see Matthew 25:1-13), there is no "bride" mentioned among them.

The only sense in which "the church collective" might be considered as "the bride of Christ" is that the New Jerusalem will be inhabited by God's people.